# Table in Reactjs Data Structures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a data structure such as:

```
[{name: 'Test', age: '2', mod_ID: 1234, mod_name: 'hat}, {name: 'Test2', age: '3', mod_ID: 43123, mod_name: sat}]
```

And others such as:

```
[{color: 'blue', size: '56'},{color: 'red', size: '32'}]
```

My react component works as such

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router';


export default class DataTable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.sortColumn = this.sortColumn.bind(this);

    }

    sortColumn(header){
        this.props.sortData(header);
    }

    displayHeaders(){
        return _.map(this.props.headers, (header, index) => <th  onClick={()=>this.sortColumn(index)}
                                                                 key={header}>{header}</th>)
    }

    render() {
        return(

            <table>
                {/*Displays the headers*/}
                <thead><tr><th></th>{this.displayHeaders()}</tr></thead>
                {/*Displays the rows*/}
                <DataRows rows={this.props.rows} form={this.props.form} />
                <Link to={{ pathname: "/NewEntry", query: {form: this.props.form}}}>
                <Button>New</Button></Link>
            </table>
        )
    }
}

class DataRows extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    displayItems(){
        return _.map(this.props.rows, (row, index) => <DataField key={index.toString()} entry={row}
                                                                 form={this.props.form}/>)
    }
    render() {
        return(<tbody>{this.displayItems()}</tbody>)

    }
}

class DataField extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


    }

    displayItems() {
        return _.map(this.props.entry, (field, index) => <td key={index.toString()}>{field}</td>)
    }


    render() {
        return (<tr>
            <EditButton entry={this.props.entry} form={this.props.form} />
            {this.displayItems()}
        </tr>)

    }
}

class EditButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<Link to={{
                pathname: "/EditEntry", query: {
                    entry: JSON.stringify(this.props.entry),
                    form: this.props.form
                }
            }}>
                <Button>Edit</Button>
            </Link>)
    }
}
```

And produces the table

```
name  age  mod_id  mod_name
Test   2   1234   hat
Test2  3   43123   sat
```

This problems is I cant think of a neat way in react to create a custom header list, sent the original item to edit entry, and exclude some fields from the data structure.

I  want the final table to look like:

```
Name   Age  Mod 
Test    2   hat
```

but EditEntry needs to be passed the original '{name: 'Test', age: '2', mod_ID: 1234, mod_name: 'hat}'

In C++ i would create a class for each object, containing the headers, display fields, and back end fields. But without writing loads of custom 'if' statements for every object what is the best way of doing this in JavaScript? The data from edit entry is going into a mysql database as a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably just create an associative array that has the key of your property name and the value of what you want the header title to be.

In other words:

```
var headerArray = [{name: "Name", age: "Age", mod_name: "Mod"}];
```

note that I left out `mod_id` since you don't want that in your final table.
You can now iterate through this array, either in a similar fashion to your `displayHeaders()`, or by iterating through your object keys:

```
Object.keys(headerArray).forEach(function(key, index) {
  //return your <th> component here
}, headerArray);
```